# Quel est le sens de « bouffer la cervelle » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Je suis en train de voir [Persepolis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808417/) et j'ai rencontré la phrase suivante :

> Tu vas voir, elle va te bouffer la cervelle.

Je n'ai pas compris cette expression. Quel est le sens de ***bouffer la cervelle*** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bouffer*, de langue populaire, dans le sens d'« [*a*]*bsorber totalement quelque chose, accaparer quelqu'un* » ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bouffer/10449)), avec généralement l'idée ici d'une opération pénible pour la personne, comme dans *se laisser (être) bouffer par qqc. ou qqn.* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bouffer)). Il est bon de rappeler que *bouffer* origine de gonfler les joues d'air, puis expirer ; éventuellement de gonfler les joues de nourriture, [devenant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/bouffer) par métonymie essentiellement *manger*, au figuré dans le sens de totalement, agressivement.

Avec [cervelle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cervelle), comme synonyme familier de *cerveau*, on a déjà des locutions du même thème (*Casser la cervelle de qqn, lui taper sur la cervelle*. L'énerver, l'exaspérer ; *Se creuser la cervelle*. Réfléchir, essayer de résoudre un problème ; *Mettre la cervelle de qqn à l'envers*. Le bouleverser ; *Tenir qqn en cervelle* (vx). Lui donner des inquiétudes). On y réfère aussi comme le siège de l'affectivité (« j'ai cru m'apercevoir tout d'un coup que Lady Falkland occupe, dans ma cervelle, beaucoup de place ; − trop de place. » Farrère).

---

Donc vu la forme pronominale, il peut s'agir de se laisser absorber, de laisser une personne, une idée, prendre toute la place dans son esprit, de la laisser attiser ses émotions, dominer ses pensées, ou de lui permettre d'empiéter avidement sur (ce qui reste de) son univers intérieur.

Answer (score 4):

"Bouffer la cervelle à quelqu'un" has a very simple translation in the Indianized flavor of English - we would say it means "to eat one's head", i.e to bother someone either by manipulating them to use their brains too much, or by trying to brainwash them.

Comment: Dans le cas présent l'expression à probablement le sens de "brainwash" je suis d'accord. Cependant, cette expression peut aussi signifier que quelque chose est obsédant. Quelqu'un qui est criblé de dettes peut aussi avoir `la cervelle bouffée` par ses problèmes.

Comment: Et n'oublions pas le sens littéral aussi... à priori plus rarement utilisé jusqu'à une invasion zombie, mais quand-même...

Comment: @Hakim, merci! Je ne savais pas cette significance de l'expression.

Comment: @LaurentS. Haha!

Comment: @Laurent tout à fait